# Modify item inside layer-list drawable xml

Tags: android, android-drawable

My question is simple, I have this file in `drawable` folder: `popup1.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:left="8dp" android:id="@+id/bm1b" >
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/flepop01" android:gravity="top|left"  ></bitmap>        
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

How I can modify the value of the property "left" programmatically from my Activity?